# WordPress - Index Page to be different then the rest of the site

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I want to modify the Index page or the Landing page of my WordPress site so that it looks different from the rest of the site. Essentially I want the body of the index page to be 5 large rotating pictures with the same static menu and header as the rest of the site but I'm not sure where and what I need to edit to make this change. I assume it has something to do with the theme itself but I thought I would ask here first to see if anyone has any expert opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a static home page by going to Appearance->Customize->Static Front Page. Then create the page under Pages->Add New. You can add whatever custom code, images, etc. that you want on that new page. With most themes, your site's header and footer will be displayed on the page automatically.

From the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the guidance I needed.